# Can the clouds on Venus and Titan be categorized in the same way as clouds on Earth?

Tags: atmosphere, planetology

E.g. are the clouds on Venus (and Titan) cumulus, stratus, cirrus, or some other type that isn't found on Earth?

Answer (score 4):

### Clouds on Venus

After a quick search, it appears the [clouds found on Venus](http://www.universetoday.com/36871/clouds-on-venus/) are different than Earth's:

> Venus is covered by a thick layer of clouds. These clouds are made
>   mostly of sulfuric acid and are very fast moving, going up to 220
>   miles per hour (350 km per hour). The clouds rotate 60 times faster
>   than the planet rotates. The clouds circle Venus in four Earth days;
>   the planet rotates around its axis in 243 Earth days. These
>   quickly-moving clouds distribute the heat around the planet, making
>   the night side hot also. V-shaped cloud patterns are visible in the
>   middle latitudes when the clouds are examined in ultraviolet light.
>   The clouds rain sulphuric acid (extremely acid rain), but this
>   corrosive precipitation does not reach the surface. The high heat
>   beneath the clouds (up to 220°C) evaporates the rain drops about 10
>   miles (30 km) above Venus. [SOURCE](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/astronomy/planets/venus/venusatmosphere.shtml)

### Clouds on Titan

According to this release by NASA, [Titan has "cirrus-like" clouds](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/cassini/whycassini/titan-clouds.html):

> Now, thin, wispy clouds of ice particles, similar to Earth's cirrus
>   clouds, are being reported by Carrie Anderson and Robert Samuelson at
>   NASA's Goddard Space Flight Center in Greenbelt, Md. The findings,
>   published February 1 in Icarus, were made using the Composite Infrared
>   Spectrometer (CIRS) on NASA's Cassini spacecraft.